# graph no actualizing on pysimplegui with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, refresh, pysimplegui

I have the following code, I want my GUI to change my two graphs everytime I press the button, but only the one in the left changes. Can someone please help me.

It's very strange because I took care of saving all the canvas and that way I can edit them  with first using .forget() but for some reason it really doesn't work for the first graph.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# VARS CONSTS:

# New figure and plot variables so we can manipulate them

_VARS = {'window': False,
         'fig_agg1': False,
         'pltFig1': False,
        'fig_agg2': False,
         'pltFig2': False}

dataSize = 1000  # For synthetic data

# Helper Functions


def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg

def update_graph(zoom,or1,or2):
    updateChart(1,zoom,or1,or2)
    updateChart(2,zoom,or1,or2)

# \\  -------- PYSIMPLEGUI -------- //

AppFont = 'Any 16'
sg.theme('DarkTeal12')

#layout = [[sg.Canvas(key='figCanvas')],
#          [sg.Button('Update', font=AppFont), sg.Button('Exit', font=AppFont)]]

control_col=sg.Column([
    [sg.Frame('Zoom',layout = [[sg.Slider(range = (0,100), orientation = 'h', key = '-ZOOM-')]])],
    [sg.Frame('Orientation 1',layout = [[sg.Slider(range = (-180,180), orientation = 'h', key = '-OR1-')]])],
    [sg.Frame('Orientation 2',layout = [[sg.Slider(range = (-180,180), orientation = 'h', key = '-OR2-')]])],
    [sg.Checkbox('Blackhole 1' , key = '-BH1-')],
    [sg.Checkbox('Blackhole 2' , key = '-BH2-')],
    [sg.Checkbox('Blackhole 3' , key = '-BH3-')],
    [sg.Button('Show', key = '-SHOW-')]
    
])

graph1_col=sg.Column([[sg.Canvas(key = '-CANVAS1-')]])
graph2_col=sg.Column([[sg.Canvas(key = '-CANVAS2-')]])

layout=[[control_col,graph1_col,graph2_col]]

#_VARS['window'] = sg.Window('Such Window',
#                            layout,
#                            finalize=True,
#                            resizable=True,
#                            location=(100, 100),
#                            element_justification="right")

_VARS['window'] =  sg.Window('Visualization', layout, finalize = True)

# \\  -------- PYSIMPLEGUI -------- //


# \\  -------- PYPLOT -------- //


def makeSynthData():
    xData = np.random.randint(100, size=dataSize)
    yData = np.random.randint(100, size=dataSize)
    zData = np.random.randint(100, size=dataSize)
    return (xData, yData, zData)


def drawChart(number):
    _VARS['pltFig'+str(number)] = plt.figure()
    dataXYZ = makeSynthData()
    #plt.plot(dataXYZ[0], dataXYZ[1],dataXYZ[2] '.k')
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.scatter3D(dataXYZ[0], dataXYZ[1], dataXYZ[2], c=dataXYZ[2], cmap='Greens')
    _VARS['fig_agg'+str(number)] = draw_figure(
        _VARS['window']['-CANVAS'+str(number)+'-'].TKCanvas, _VARS['pltFig'+str(number)])


# Recreate Synthetic data, clear existing figre and redraw plot.

def updateChart(number,zoom,or1,or2):
    _VARS['fig_agg'+str(number)].get_tk_widget().forget()
    dataXYZ = makeSynthData()
    # plt.cla()
    plt.clf()
    #plt.plot(dataXYZ[0], dataXYZ[1], '.k')
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.scatter3D(dataXYZ[0], dataXYZ[1], dataXYZ[2], c=dataXYZ[2], cmap='Greens')
    ax.view_init(or1, or2)
    _VARS['fig_agg'+str(number)] = draw_figure(
        _VARS['window']['-CANVAS'+str(number)+'-'].TKCanvas, _VARS['pltFig'+str(number)])

# \\  -------- PYPLOT -------- //


drawChart(1)
drawChart(2)

# MAIN LOOP

while True:
    event, values = _VARS['window'].read(timeout = 50)
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == '-SHOW-':
        print(values)
        update_graph( 
                 values['-ZOOM-'],
                 values['-OR1-'],
                 values['-OR2-'])
        
        
_VARS['window'].close()
```

Comment: "but only the one in the left changes" ? It should the one in the right ?

Answer (score 1):

For `plt.figure`

- Option `num`: A unique identifier for the figure.
- If a figure with that identifier already exists, this figure is made active and returned.

Following code set which figure activated to draw

```py
def drawChart(number):
    _VARS['pltFig'+str(number)] = plt.figure()
```

After

```py
drawChart(1)
drawChart(2)
```

Active figure set to figure 2 and **not been changed** until script end.

Try to update following statement in your code.

```py
def drawChart(number):
    _VARS['pltFig'+str(number)] = plt.figure(num=number)
```

```py
def updateChart(number,zoom,or1,or2):
    _VARS['fig_agg'+str(number)].get_tk_widget().forget()
    dataXYZ = makeSynthData()
    plt.figure(num=number)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much it totally fixed the problem ! :)